# Divide data pairs via jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using jQuery, I want to select some data and divide the pairs with a delimiter.

My code:

```
var checkboxes = [];
$('input[name="CheckBox3"]:checked,select[name=ansprechpartner]').each(function() {
    checkboxes.push($(this).val());
    checkboxes.push(":");
});
```

Code output:

```
1998,:,1292,2006,:,1128,2630,:,3030,:
```

Desired code output:

```
1998:1292,2006:1128,2630:3030
```

Sample HTML

```
<tr class="Row">
    <td style="TEXT-ALIGN: right">
        <input type="checkbox" id="kontakteCheckBox3" class="idRow" value="2006" name="CheckBox3">&nbsp;</td>
    <select id="ansprechpartner" class="ansprechpartner" name="ansprechpartner">
        <option selected value="">-</option>
        <OPTION VALUE="1292">Abels</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="1295">Delta</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="1298">Extra</OPTION>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="Row">
    <td style="TEXT-ALIGN: right">
        <input type="checkbox" id="kontakteCheckBox3" class="idRow" value="2008" name="CheckBox3">&nbsp;</td>
    <select id="ansprechpartner" class="ansprechpartner" name="ansprechpartner">
        <option selected value="">-</option>
        <OPTION VALUE="1392">Abels</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="1495">Delta</OPTION>
        <OPTION VALUE="1198">Extra</OPTION>
    </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I don't know how to fix it.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var checkboxes = $('input[name="CheckBox3"]:checked').map(function () {
    return this.value + ':' + $(this).closest('tr').find('select').val();
}).get();
var str = checkboxes.join(':')
```

Comment: thanks, it works, but the pairs should also be devided with the delimiter ,

Comment: @user2083524 what are the pairings? checkbox:checkbox or checkbox:select

Comment: is the value from one checkbox and one select a pair? can you share the html as well

Comment: the select is not multi-select and the pair is checkbox:select

Comment: @user2083524 so every checked checkbox has a select... can you share the html as well

Comment: @user2083524 see the update... whether the checkbox and the select are in the same td or in different `td` elements next to each other

Answer (score 0):

Revised solution

Based on provided html, traverse parent row

```
var output=$('input[name="CheckBox3"]:checked').map(function(){
    var selVal=$(this).closest('tr').find('select[name=ansprechpartner]').val() | 0;
  return  this.value +':'+ selVal;
}).get().join()
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3cWyh/1)**</kbd>

Comment: can try this...without seeing some html to reference have to assune can use index...traverse would work if could see html

Comment: the output is always: 1998:1292:2006:1128:2630:2354

Comment: delete that comment and post code in question where it will be formatted and other readers will see it

Comment: index will work...or use second version but switch `form` for `tr`

Comment: make sure remove `:` from join, default delimter of `join` is a comma

Comment: great job @charlietf, the first code works for me, the result now is 1998:1292,2006:,2640 is it possible to set 0 if the select value is empty ?

Comment: add `| 0` after `.val()`....First one won't work, if any checkbox not checked will throw indexing off